# combining linq queries without redundant code

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Hey guys thanks in advance for any help. I'm a front end developer, but recently I've been working on some more full-stack bugs. I'm pretty new to C#, and I want to refactor this query to cut down on redundancy. How can I combine these two linq queries into 1 so that I only need 1 query.Each statement instead of two identical ones? I've tried something like var query1 = xxx then query2 = query1.Where... but I can't get the syntax quite right. Thanks again.

```
public interface ILoginLinkService 
{
    Dictionary<string, IList<NameValuePair>> GetLoginPageLinks();
}

public class LoginLinkService : ILoginLinkService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public LoginLinkService(IUnitOfWork unitofwork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitofwork;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, IList<NameValuePair>> GetLoginPageLinks()
    {
        var data = new Dictionary<string, IList<NameValuePair>>();

        var query = (from s in unitOfWork.Repository<LoginPageLink>().Queryable()
                     orderby s.LoginPageLinkCategory.Code, s.SortOrder
                         select new 
                         {
                             s.LoginPageLinkCategory.Code,
                             s.Name,
                             s.Url,
                         });
        query.Each(x =>
        {
            var pair = new NameValuePair() {Name = x.Name, Value = x.Url,};
            IList<NameValuePair> list;
            if (data.ContainsKey(x.Code))
            {
                list = data[x.Code];
            }
            else
            {
                list = new List<NameValuePair>();
                data[x.Code] = list;
            }
            list.Add(pair);
        });

        var announcementsQuery = (from s in unitOfWork.Repository<LoginPageLink>().Queryable()
                                  .Where(x => x.LoginPageLinkCategory.Code == LoginPageLinkCategory.AnnouncementsCode &&
                                   (DbFunctions.DiffDays(x.CreatedDate, DateTimeOffset.Now) ?? 0) <= 7)
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      s.LoginPageLinkCategory.Code,
                                      s.Name,
                                      s.Url,
                                  });
        announcementsQuery.Each(x =>
        {
            var pair = new NameValuePair() { Name = x.Name, Value = x.Url, };
            IList<NameValuePair> list;
            if (data.ContainsKey(x.Code))
            {
                list = data[x.Code];
            }
            else
            {
                list = new List<NameValuePair>();
                data[x.Code] = list;
            }
            list.Add(pair);
        });

        return data;
    }        
}
```

Comment: You can't just paste a lot of code and ask other people to fix it. Google some tutorials and get to work.

Comment: You havent even shown your `Each`-method. Why don't you use a `foreach`? In general such a method  _"violates the functional programming principles that all the other sequence operators are based upon. Clearly the sole purpose of a call to this method is to cause side effects. The purpose of an expression is to compute a value, not to cause a side effect. The purpose of a statement is to cause a side effect"_ ([“foreach” vs “ForEach”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/))

Comment: Please reformat your question to show a bare minimum, verifiable example of the data, the linq queries, and what you have tried to do to combine them yourself and this question will go a lot further.

Comment: I wonder why you would want to do that? In my opinion the split in queries makes the code readable. Combining the queries would make it hard to read (whenever you have a bug in the code.

Comment: I don't see how you can combine them since the where includes logic on a column that isn't part of the select.

Comment: I like creating a help function.  So the where becomes .Where(x => Helper(x, option)).  Then the helper would be public static Boolean Helper(object x, string option){ enter code here }.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it. @hellogoodnight your answer was particularly helpful. Thanks anyway guys...
 namespace xxx.Business.Common.Services
{

```
public interface ILoginLinkService
{

    Dictionary<string, IList<NameValuePair>> GetLoginPageLinks();

}

public class LoginLinkService : ILoginLinkService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public LoginLinkService(IUnitOfWork unitofwork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitofwork;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, IList<NameValuePair>> GetLoginPageLinks()
    {
        var data = new Dictionary<string, IList<NameValuePair>>();

        var baseQuery = unitOfWork.Repository<LoginPageLink>().Queryable();

        var nonAnnouncementsQuery = baseQuery
            .Where(x => x.LoginPageLinkCategory.Code != LoginPageLinkCategory.AnnouncementsCode)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.LoginPageLinkCategory.Code,
                x.Name,
                x.Url,
                x.SortOrder
            });

        var announcementsQuery = baseQuery
            .Where(x => x.LoginPageLinkCategory.Code == LoginPageLinkCategory.AnnouncementsCode &&
                (DbFunctions.DiffDays(x.CreatedDate, DateTimeOffset.Now) ?? 0) <= 7)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.LoginPageLinkCategory.Code,
                x.Name,
                x.Url,
                x.SortOrder
            });

        var fullQuery = nonAnnouncementsQuery.Union(announcementsQuery)
            .OrderBy(x => new { x.Code, x.SortOrder })
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.Code,
                x.Name,
                x.Url
            });

        fullQuery.Each(x =>
        {
            var pair = new NameValuePair() { Name = x.Name, Value = x.Url, };
            IList<NameValuePair> list;
            if (data.ContainsKey(x.Code))
            {
                list = data[x.Code];
            }
            else
            {
                list = new List<NameValuePair>();
                data[x.Code] = list;
            }
            list.Add(pair);
        });

        return data;
    }
}
```

}